# Mode line will not redraw properly

Tags: emacs, modeline

Customizing my emacs modeline and after adding box with positive line width, I start seeing line number and column number redrawn on top of each other, like this:

[image: modeline]

As you can see in the picture I have line-width of 3 for the box. If I try to reset it to -1,the problem disappears. What is the issue here?

I am running macos Sierra 10.12.6 and emacs 25.3.1 (outside terminal)

Comment: If the problem persists after evaluating `(force-mode-line-update t)`, then the problem is not likely due to redrawing.  You can also evaluate `(redraw-frame)` to test the redrawing theory.  If you eliminate the redrawing issue, then what remains is likely a spacing / font issue -- i.e., what you want to do does not fit, so you may wish to experiment with changing other aspects of the mode-line so that everything fits as desired -- e.g., font, height, spaces, XPM images if any, etc.  A mode-line might have lots of different faces that are being used at different locations.

Comment: @lawlist redrawing the frame removes all the mess, but when I switch to the next line/column, it gets all messed up again

Comment: It could be a bug, but the mode-line is a Pandora's Box -- i.e., the components are an endless possibility of user customizations.  If you have a recipe to reproduce the issue from Emacs -Q, then you may wish to see if the issue persists with Emacs 26 (soon to be released).  If it also exists with Emacs 26, then submit a bug report.  It doesn't sound like something that can be resolved on stackoverflow, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: @lawlist That's weird, I don't have that many customizations (don't even use any packages for mode line). I'll try to update everything including OS and see if it helps. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is fixed in emacs 26.1